# ExtJs 4 Proxy Writer and PHP $_POST

Tags: javascript, php, extjs, extjs4

I have this store:

```
Ext.define('strMtoOrganismos', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
model:  'mdlMtoOrganismos',
autoLoad: false,
pageSize: 20,
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    api: {
        read: 'some php url',
        update: 'some php url'
    },
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'data',
        totalProperty: 'total',
        successProperty: 'success'
    },
    writer: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'data',
        encode: true,
        writeAllFields: false,
    }
}
});
```

In my controller I have a button that sync the store:

```
onPulsarGuardar:function(){
    Ext.getStore('strMtoOrganismos').sync();
}
```

And in my php file,printing $_POST[data] I receive for example:
{"codigo_erp_cliente":"243","id":2}

How can I convert this string to an array like:

[codigo_erp_cliente]=>243

[id]=>2

Or an alternative configuration to the store writer?

Comment: [PHP: json_decode - Manual](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: In my php file i use :  

$records=$_POST[records];  
$json=json_decode($records);  
print_r($json);

And get an error:
[E] Ext.JSON.decode(): You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String: Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [codigo_erp_cliente] => 24444555
            [id] => 2
        )

)

Comment: Forget this,the error is because I´m printing the array in the php to see the values,I only must return once the php is finished if all is correct: echo json_encode(array(
  "success"  => 1
));